# Checking if correct value is outputed Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, assertions

I tried to word the title as clearly as possible. I'm new to unit testing, and I have a handle on some of the more basic types of assertions, but there is one test I haven't figured out. So I have user enter some type of input and I print the output by calling the variable preceding some type of message. Here is the py file the testsuite is testing

```
def get_input()
    pirateInput = input("What be ye name?! ")
    print("Ahoy Captain ", pirateInput)
```

The user enters a name and I just print it out. So the expected output should be "Ahoy Captain [user input]"

Here is my test suite

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from get_input import *

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_ValuePrints(self):
      #patch input as 'Hook'
      @patch('builtins.input', return_value='Hook'

          saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          get_input()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          assert output == 'Ahoy Captain Hook'
      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
   unittest.main()
```

So I check for the output I'm expecting, but the test does patch the input as expected. I don't know if I'm clear but hopefully someone can help. If you need more detail please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is missing some parts and is syntactically incorrect. Your `GetInputTest` should have at least one method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is pretty simple. The `print` function already adds a space between each pair of arguments, so if you do

```
print("Ahoy Captain ", pirateInput)
```

It will print: `Ahoy Captain  Hook`. Notice the two spaces, the one you add at the end of the first string and the one added by `print`. Just remove the one in your string and it will work.

Here's a full **working** example:

```
import unittest
import sys
import io
import logging

from unittest.mock import patch

def get_input():
    pirateInput = input("What be ye name?! ")
    print("Ahoy Captain", pirateInput)

class GetInputTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('builtins.input', return_value='Hook')
    def test_ValuePrints(self, sth):
      log = logging.getLogger( "SomeTest.testSomething" )
      saved_stdout = sys.stdout
      try:
          out = io.StringIO()
          sys.stdout = out
          get_input()
          output = out.getvalue().strip()
          log.debug(output)
          assert output == 'Ahoy Captain Hook'
      finally:
          sys.stdout = saved_stdout

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig( stream=sys.stderr )
    logging.getLogger( "SomeTest.testSomething" ).setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
    unittest.main()
```

Test run:

```
$ python3 main.py 
DEBUG:SomeTest.testSomething:Ahoy Captain Hook
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Comment: Awesome! works lovely. Can you explain what the logging does? and is it completely necessary? I've been writing unit test without them and they work fine, so what benefit do we get from it?

Comment: The logging can be deleted safely. I just used it to print the value of the `output` variable, but you can remove it.